# Build a simple calculator using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to build a simple calculator using threads in C language, code is given below..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 
typedef struct Calc {
    int a,b;
}C;

void *add(void* arg) {
    C* temp = (Calc *)arg;
    int ans= temp->a + temp->b;
    printf("Sum is %d\n",ans);
    return NULL;
}
void *sub(void* arg) {
    C* temp = (Calc *)arg;
    int ans= temp->a - temp->b;
    printf("Sub is %d\n",ans);
    return NULL;
}
void *mul(void* arg) {
    C* temp = (Calc *)arg;
    int ans= temp->a * temp->b;
    printf("mul is %d\n",ans);
    return NULL;
} 
void *div(void* arg) {
    C* temp = (Calc *)arg;
    int ans= temp->a / temp->b;
    printf("div is %d\n",ans);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3, t4;
    C* calc = (Calc *)malloc(sizeof(C));    
    calc->a = 7;
    calc->b = 4;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,add(calc),NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,sub(calc),NULL);
    pthread_create(&t3,NULL,mul(calc),NULL);
    pthread_create(&t4,NULL,div(calc),NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And i got an error everytime while calling a function for Ex..

```
argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(*)(void *)"
40    |     pthread_create(&t2,NULL,sub(calc),NULL);
      |                             ~~~^~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                void*
```

Can anyone tell me whats the error and how to solve it?

Thank You :)

Comment: I would start by changing all of your `Calc` references to `C` or `struct Calc`.

Comment: `pthread_create` expects a function pointer and an argument.

Comment: (preferably `C`, since you're using a `typedef`.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I got that but what about error?

Comment: Expanding on Botje's comment: `add(calc)` is a function call that returns a pointer to `void`. You want to pass in the function, not the result of calling the function.

Comment: In addition, allowing main() to return will terminate the process.  When the OS terminates a process, it terminates all process threads, quite possibly before they have calculated anything:(

Comment: `pthread_create(&t1,NULL,add,calc);` and so on... then `pthread_join(t1, NULL);` and so on at the end of `main()`.

Comment: FYI: This assignment maybe will teach you something about how to create threads, but you should be aware that it is a spectacularly bad example of _why_ to create threads. A thread should do a whole lot more work than just adding two numbers before it's worthwhile to create it.

Comment: `div` is already defined in `stdlib.h`. You should give your function another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To largely summarize the comments:*

First and foremost, threads are definite overkill for this type of program, but it's fine to start learning somewhere.

Decide on one identifier to use for your structure type (references to `Calc` should be `C` or `struct Calc`).

That said, there's no need to explicitly cast a `void *` to another pointer type - that is handled implicitly and safely during assignment. For example,

```
C *temp = arg;
```

and

```
C *calc = malloc(sizeof *calc);
```

both work just fine, and are preferred.

`C` is a pretty poor type identifier, though; try something more readable.

---

Here

```
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, add(calc), NULL);
```

you are attempting to call `add` (itself with an incorrect argument type), and pass the result of that function as the third argument to `pthread_create`.

`pthread_create` expects a *function pointer*, with the signature `void *(*)(void *)`, as its third argument. This function is used as the entry point for the thread; also called the *start routine*.

The fourth argument should be a `void *`, which is the pointer passed to the thread's start routine.

---

Your threads may not finish their execution before the `main` function of the program exits. To wait for a thread to finish you can use `pthread_join`, which takes a thread as its first argument, and a `void **` as its second argument - a place to store the pointer than is returned from thread's start routine (or more specifically, the `pthread_exit` function).

```
pthread_join(t1, NULL);
```

This function will block execution of the *calling thread* until the specified thread has finished. If the specified thread has already finished, `pthread_join` returns immediately.

---

Here is a minimal version of your program, with just a single `add` thread to focus on. Note that dynamically allocating memory is largely unnecessary in this example.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} Calculator;

void *add(void *arg) {
    Calculator *temp = arg;
    int ans = temp->a + temp->b;

    printf("Sum is %d\n", ans);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t t1; /* ...and so on */
    Calculator calc = { .a = 7, .b = 4 };

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, add, &calc);
    /* ...and so on */

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    /* ...and so on */
}
```

Simply duplicate the `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` functions, with your different threads and start routines to expand this. Note that all the calls to `pthread_create` should occur before any calls to `pthread_join`, if you want concurrency.

---

Note that `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` both use their return values to signal success or failure (`0` on success, otherwise, an error number).

It'd be wise to check these values for errors (use `strerror` to get printable strings).

---

Further addendums:

- `int main()` should really be `int main(void)`, or `int main(int argc, char **argv` (or equivalent).
- There exists a `div` function in the standard library. To avoid conflict, you'll need to use a different name.